# Wrong font for digits in math-mode

Tags: fonts, luatex

in my minimum example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}    
\usepackage{newtxsf}
\begin{document}
This is a test: $5$ = 5
\end{document}
```

compiled with `lualatex -shell-escape doc.tex` I get a wrong font for math-digits:
[image: wrong-font-math-digits]

What can I do to get the same digits as in non-math-mode?

Comment: Why you say *wrong*? It is math font, not equal to text font. This is acceptable. Of course, depending which text font you use, it could be *ugly*, but not *wrong*.

Comment: I'd like the math-font to be equal or at least similar to the text-font. Digits should look the same.

Comment: @Sigur With `newtxsf` the math should be sans serif.

Comment: @user2033412 Would compiling with pdflatex be a workaround?

Comment: @samcarter: nope -- The build-server uses `lualatex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With lining numbers it's not so difficult.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lining,scaled=0.9]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{newtxsf}

\DeclareSymbolFont{digits}{TU}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`9}

\begin{document}
This is a test: $0123456789$ = 0123456789

$a-b=c$ abc

\end{document}
```

[image]